# Simple way to publish opensrc Java project to maven

Tags: java, maven

Many years ago via java.net I made an opensrc project available on Maven Central, it was difficult. I tried to make a newer version available after java.net folded and I couldn't get it working, I gave up. Many years later the project is still going strong but the maven repository has not been updated, I am always being asked to do it but I really don't know how to progress.

So please are there some complete steps to deploy a java lib to maven central repository so I can get this resolved.

Comment: Hi Paul! I would guess you do it by using the maven plugin and just deploy to the maven factory? So I'd suggest you look at Maven/Deploy

Comment: Yeah, in my company we have our own factory. So I guess the process would be similar. We just use the Maven plugin to deploy it. If you use Intellij or Eclipse, the built-in maven Plugin should be useful. You probably need to configure credentails, release tag and so on. Here's actually a page on it https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: This guide also explains it: but basically, you need to configure your pom and credentials. Then you can use the deploy method in the plugin. https://dzone.com/articles/publish-your-artifacts-to-maven-central

Comment: https://central.sonatype.org/

Comment: Right well tried to follow dzone instructions, project is already bitbucket (i assume I can use that instead of github) I have created a sonatype account and submitted an issue but no real idea of what i was meant to put in the issue. I had hoped for better because I am a Java expert not a maven central expert, why cant they make it easier.

Comment: closed by ticket, something wrong with it but they didnt explain what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @khmarbaise indicated in [his comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63155573/simple-way-to-publish-opensrc-java-project-to-maven#comment111681114_63155573), you should follow [Sonatype's guide to publishing content to Maven Central](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html).

(Part of the reason why they "cant…make it easier" is that whatever content you push has to be provably owned by you and will live, hopefully, forever in Maven Central under what will be eternal coordinates.  That's a deliberately high barrier to entry.  It is also what makes the facility so powerful.)

Comment: I dont buy that argument, they could certainly make the instructions much easirer with concrete examples.

Comment: Each of something on the order of ten videos walks you through each step. Disclaimer: I have no stake here one way or the other. Here is the issue I filed to start my Central process many moons ago: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-27964 I hope this helps.

Comment: With help I have eventually got sonatype working.